# How to toggle class when click outside element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the [free example navbar on tailwindui](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/navigation/navbars). I wrote some javascript to be able to toggle the menu on mobile and toggle the profile pic tooltip. However the profile pic tooltip doesn't close on clicks outside it.

My current javascript code only toggles the profile pic tooltip on and off when it's clicked. It doesn't hide the tooltip when outside it is clicked.

I tried using a click event listener and toggle the tooltip off when the event listener fired but that didn't work.

Using Javascript, how would you hide the profile pic tooltip on outside clicks?

```js
  
  document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("resultnav").classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
  
  //document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function () {
  //  document.getElementById("toggleme").classList.toggle("hidden");
  //}
  
  
  document.getElementById('toggleprofile').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("resultprofile").classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="bg-gray-800">
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="relative flex items-center justify-between h-16">
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
        <!-- Mobile menu button-->
        <button id="togglemebutton" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 focus:text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Main menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <!-- Icon when menu is closed. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" -->
          <svg class="block h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
          <!-- Icon when menu is open. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
          <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
          <img class="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
          <img class="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
        </div>
        <div class="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6">
          <div class="flex">
            <a href="#" class="px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
        <button class="p-1 border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-full hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Notifications">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
          </svg>
        </button>

        <!-- Profile dropdown -->
        <div class="ml-3 relative">
          <div>
            <button id="toggleprofile" class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" id="user-menu" aria-label="User menu" aria-haspopup="true">
              <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            </button>
          </div>
          <!--
            Profile dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.

            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
              From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
              From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          -->
          <div id="resultprofile" class="hidden z-40 origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg">
            <div class="py-1 rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Your Profile</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Settings</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Sign out</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
    Mobile menu, toggle classes based on menu state.

    Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden"
  -->
  <div id="resultnav" class="hidden sm:hidden">
    <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3">
      <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: insert css pls!

Comment: There is no CSS because the code uses Tailwind. If you click the run code button it should show everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using a click event listener and toggle the tooltip off when
> the event listener fired but that didn't work.

This is exactly what you need, event listener on all elements:

```
const toggleprofile = document.getElementById("toggleprofile");
const resultprofile = document.getElementById("resultprofile");

[...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
//in order to get all elements
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
//add click event to all of them
    if (event.target.parentElement.id !== "toggleprofile") {
// if element is not profile picture - parent button has id, easier to target
      console.clear();
      console.log(event.target.parentElement.id)
      resultprofile.classList.add("hidden")
//add class
    }else{
    resultprofile.classList.toggle("hidden")}
//if it is profile, toggle class
  })
})
```

Keep in mind now you have click event listener on all elements on page, so if you need something else with other element, just expand this.

**Working example:**

```js
document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("resultnav").classList.toggle("hidden");
}

//document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function () {
//  document.getElementById("toggleme").classList.toggle("hidden");
//}


const toggleprofile = document.getElementById("toggleprofile");
const resultprofile = document.getElementById("resultprofile");
[...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.parentElement.id !== "toggleprofile") {
      console.clear();
      console.log(event.target.parentElement.id)
      resultprofile.classList.add("hidden")
    }else{
    resultprofile.classList.toggle("hidden")}
  })
})
```

```css
body{
height:300px}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="bg-gray-800">
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="relative flex items-center justify-between h-16">
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
        <!-- Mobile menu button-->
        <button id="togglemebutton" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 focus:text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Main menu"
          aria-expanded="false">
          <!-- Icon when menu is closed. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" -->
          <svg class="block h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
          <!-- Icon when menu is open. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
          <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
          <img class="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
          <img class="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
        </div>
        <div class="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6">
          <div class="flex">
            <a href="#" class="px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
        <button class="p-1 border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-full hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Notifications">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
          </svg>
        </button>

        <!-- Profile dropdown -->
        <div class="ml-3 relative">
          <div>
            <button id="toggleprofile" class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" id="user-menu" aria-label="User menu" aria-haspopup="true">
              <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            </button>
          </div>
          <!--
            Profile dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.

            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
              From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
              From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          -->
          <div id="resultprofile" class="hidden z-40 origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg">
            <div class="py-1 rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Your Profile</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Settings</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Sign out</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
    Mobile menu, toggle classes based on menu state.

    Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden"
  -->
  <div id="resultnav" class="hidden sm:hidden">
    <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3">
      <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or as mentioned in comment:

```
window.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.parentElement.id !== "toggleprofile") {
    console.clear();
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.id);
    resultprofile.classList.add("hidden")
  } else {
    resultprofile.classList.toggle("hidden")
  }
})
```

Comment: could also add the listener to the window object itself.

Comment: How would using window/document work for the event listener part?window.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.parentElement.id !== "toggleprofile") {
      console.clear();
      console.log(event.target.parentElement.id)
      resultprofile.classList.add("hidden")
    }else{
    resultprofile.classList.toggle("hidden")}
  })

Answer (score -1):

[image: As you can see this snippet isn't responsive @this very dimensions]

[image: now it becomes in less dimensions]

**I'll try to improve this others are requested to do the same**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29995210)